# Python permutation as list comprehension

Tags: python, list, permutation, list-comprehension

I've got a list of strings and a permutation. I'm trying to apply the permutation to the list, but I'm trying to keep my code clean and concise. At the moment I have a working solution, and it looks like this:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
permutation = [5,2,6,3,7,9,1,4,8]

mynewlist = ['']*9
for i in range(9):
    mynewlist[permutation[i]-1] = mylist[i]

print mynewlist
```

What I don't like about it is that I have to initialize the list to an empty list first, and then loop through it in an odd manner. I was just wondering if someone could come up with a cleaner way to write this, perhaps using a list comprehension? Or by applying a map?

For reference purposes - the result of the above is:

```
['g', 'b', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm, but cleaner:

```
mynewlist = mylist[:]
for pos, elem in zip(permutation, mylist):
    mynewlist[pos - 1] = elem
```

Comment: I'm accepting this, since there appears to be no suitable alternative that increases readability as much as you have. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning - I ended up replacing mylist[:] with list(mylist), as it might be clearer to those unfamiliar with Python/Perl.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use `sorted()`:

```
sorted(mylist, key=lambda v, i=iter(permutation): next(i))
```

This outputs:

```
>>> sorted(mylist, key=lambda v, i=iter(permutation): next(i))
['g', 'b', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f']
```

This sorts the input `mylist` according to the indices taken from the `permutation` list; the `key` function is called for each element in the input sequence in order, once, before sorting.

This does not compare that favorably with your version though; you have a O(n) algorithm, this takes O(n lg n).

Comment: That's what I thought at first, too. But the result is incorrect - the permutation is applied the wrong way around. (Result: ['e', 'b', 'f', 'c', 'g', 'i', 'a', 'd', 'h'])

Comment: This looks kinda fragile. Can you guarantee `sorted` calls `key` in order and always will?

Comment: @PavelAnossov: Yes, sorted will call `key()` in order.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Out of curiosity, can you see anything wrong with my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Just a crazy thought, but how about...

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
>>> permutation = [5,2,6,3,7,9,1,4,8]
>>> {permutation[i]: v for i, v in enumerate(mylist)}.values()
['g', 'b', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f']
```

...exploiting the fact that dictionaries are sorted by hash values, and integers hash to their own value.

I think this is an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: It is only by luck that this works; python dictionaries are *not* ordered; only because python integers are hashed to themselves *and* because you didn't get any collisions on those hashes did this work at all.

Comment: For this to work in the *general* case you'd need a sort step still.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah. I did say it was a "crazy thought". I guess it's not good practice to rely on Python internals in this way. Thanks for taking a look, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
mynewlist = [list_item for p, list_item in sorted(zip(permutation, mylist))]
```

The result is:

```
['g', 'b', 'd', 'h', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'f']
```

#### Discussion

Let's start from the right. The `zip()` function couples the two lists together:

```
>>> zip(permutation, mylist)
[(5, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (6, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (7, 'e'), (9, 'f'), (1, 'g'), (4, 'h'), (8, 'i')]
```

We can then sort the result of the `zip()` function, which will produce a list of tuples sorted by permutation index:

```
>>> sorted(zip(permutation, mylist))
[(1, 'g'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'h'), (5, 'a'), (6, 'c'), (7, 'e'), (8, 'i'), (9, 'f')]
```

This is almost what we want: the characters are in order. The next step is to eliminate the permutation index, leaving just the characters. That's the final form I presented above.